# How to Create a Custom Error Page in Azure AD B2C | Custom Policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

When using [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom), how can I specify the error page for a `<UserJourney>`?  Based on the values in the TFP base xml file, I would have thought it would be `<RecoveryUri>` but that is not working.

```xml
<ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin-ext-local">
    <!-- <LoadUri>~/tenant/default/unified.cshtml</LoadUri> -->
    <LoadUri>https://localhost:44377/</LoadUri>
    <!-- <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri> -->
    <RecoveryUri>https://localhost:44377/Home/Error</RecoveryUri>
    <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.0.0</DataUri>
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
    </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>
```

---

Current Result:

[image: current error view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to update the `api.error` content definition:

```xml
<!-- This content definition is to render an error page that displays unhandled errors. -->
<ContentDefinition Id="api.error">
  <LoadUri>~/tenant/default/exception.cshtml</LoadUri>
  <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
  <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:globalexception:1.1.0</DataUri>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="DisplayName">Error page</Item>
  </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>
```

Comment: *When* would this content definition be used by B2C? We have a similar definition, but the error page is never displayed. If you have any thoughts, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51088275/azure-active-directory-b2c-custom-error-page-is-ignored

Comment: Just you note you change the "LoadUri" in this instance.

Comment: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/creating-an-error-page-for-an-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-flow-fb2692a3b50f