# Custom error messages or error page in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is there a way to configure custom error messages or maybe even a custom error page in Azure Active Directory to display when something goes wrong during sign in instead of the "Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in." text and error details?

I was not able to find any documentation on this but after further digging I found that there is a `errorUrl` parameter in the application (app registered in the AAD and used for sign in) `manifest`. My initial thought was that in case of an error MS/AAD would redirect to this url with the error codes but as far as I have tested this `errorUrl` url does not seem to be used at all.

What is the `errorUrl` parameter meant for and is there realy no way to specify/configure custom error messages?

Comment: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/creating-an-error-page-for-an-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-flow-fb2692a3b50f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to specify custom error messages or error pages.

In certain flows, in certain cases, the error message is passed back to your application (instead of being displayed in the Azure AD sign-in page) where you can deal with it as you see fit. (I don't believe there is any standard guidance on which error cases result in an error returned back to the app.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to custom error page, you can use [custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom) in Azure AD B2C. For more details, please refer to the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51088275/azure-active-directory-b2c-custom-error-page-is-ignored.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but we're using the B2B Azure AD.

Comment: If you’re a Microsoft partner, I recommend you visiting aka.ms/devchat for personalized support on Azure. It’s free and 24x5.