# Change Password with Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are following [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-password-change#:~:text=Choose%20All%20services%20in%20the,for%20and%20select%20the%20TrustframeworkExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-password-change#:%7E:text=Choose%20All%20services%20in%20the,for%20and%20select%20the%20TrustframeworkExtensions). to setup change password via custom policy.
Positive scenario works well, however, if a user provides incorrect old password, we get a message 'The username or password provided in the request are invalid.' Didn't find from where the message is coming.
Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: Any help please.

Comment: It should be from the `ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted"`. If you want to customize it, please look into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798311/how-to-create-a-custom-error-page-in-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies?answertab=votes#tab-top.

Comment: Hi, Yes it should be in api.selfasserted but do you have the string id against which I can put in the localization text. I couldn’t find the id in MS documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Verify in your validation technical profile in the metadata and confirm whether this is the information. see example below:

```
      <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">We can't seem to find your account</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfInvalidPassword">**Your password is incorrect**</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfOldPasswordUsed">Looks like you used an old password</Item>

        <Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">query</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">email openid</Item>
        <Item Key="grant_type">password</Item>

        <!-- Policy Engine Clients -->
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
      </Metadata>
```