# Azure b2c change password How to avoid prompt=login parameter from url

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

When I clicked on change password in our app . you are redirect to the change password custom policy in b2c.ask for login again if user is already sign in via b2c .how to avoid login process and how to remove prompt=login from url?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if below reference can be helpful.

Verify in your validation technical profile in the metadata if prompt key is present and confirm and avoid prompt=login by giving  the `prompt=none`  and should be paired with a `login_hint` to indicate which user must be signed in.

> These parameters ensure that the user isn't presented with any
> interactive prompt at all.

```
 <TechnicalProfiles>
  <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
     <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
   <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <Metadata>
        ...
        ...

<Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>
<Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
<Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token</Item>
<Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
<Item Key="response_mode">query</Item>
<Item Key="scope">email openid</Item>
<Item Key="grant_type">password</Item>

<!-- Policy Engine Clients -->
<Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
<Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
```

**References:**

1. [Microsoft identity platform and OpenID Connect protocol - Microsoft
   identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-the-sign-in-request)
2. [azure ad b2c - Change Password with Custom Policy - Stack
   Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64880000/change-password-with-custom-policy)

Comment: What is “prompt key” that should be present?